# How do I find out whether a ResourceManager contains a key without calling ResourceManager.GetString() and catching the exception?

Tags: .net, c++, localization

So I have a ResourceManager that points to a resource file with a bunch of strings in it. When I call `GetString()` with a key that doesn't exist in the file, I get a `System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException`. I need to find out whether the Resource contains the specified key without using exception handling to control program flow. Is there a keys.exists() method or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by default, it appears that a new .net project's Resources.resx is going to be in the Properties folder, so you'll need to create the ResourceManager like this:

```
rm = new ResourceManager("MyNamespace.Properties.MyResource", assembly);
```

Alternatively, by getting frustrated and deleting/recreating Resources.resx, you'll probably create it in the root of the project, in which case the thing you were doing before, namely this:

```
rm = new ResourceManager("MyNamespace.MyResource", assembly);
```

will work.  This is exactly what happened to me today, and I'm adding this post in the hope that it will spare someone some grief.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the GetString method with a key that doesn't exist does not raise an exception, it just returns null.

However, the MissingManifestResourceException occurrs when trying to create a ResourceManager with the wrong name. The most common error is to forget to include the namespace in the name of the resources.

For example, doing :

```
var r = new ResourceManager("MyResource", assembly);
```

instead of

```
var r = new ResourceManager("MyNamespace.MyResource", assembly);
```

will result in a MissingManifestResourceException.

Comment: In my case it throws `MissingManifestResourceException` exception even if resource name is correct  but cannot find key!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem was, but I got frustrated and deleted/recreated the resx files and this worked.